# Nativescript tns module

Tags: nativescript

> System.err: 
>       System.err: Error calling module function 
>       System.err: 
>       System.err: TypeError: application_1.run is not a function
>       System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.HelloWorld/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js,
>   line: 158, column: 22

while i am building a nativescript application. I am getti9ng above mentioned error . CAn anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Can you provide the part of the code which is breaking and the command you use to run the build ?

Comment: Its not because of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `run` was introduced with NativeScript 4.0.0 so make sure you are using `tns-core-modules@4.0.0` or above. Also, use the latest `tns-android` and `tns-ios` for full compatibility with the latest modules.

Comment: Thank You. Actually those types of error comes, when our node and other tns modules are messed up. so i unintalled node , npm and nativescript and installed latest again. Now everything working fine.